# Can someone tell me what am I doing wrong here in my Java code when trying to find count of substrings in given string according to given queries?

Tags: java, arrays, string, substring

There are queries in array findStr, and for each query, I am given a target suffix. I have to determine the count of strings in the array strr that have the suffix as the target suffix. The queries are given as an array of strings findStr.

**Example**

Assumptions

strr = ["asdfc", "asfc", "vdsfc", "trgfds", "egregds", "tertdfc", "rtyergds"]

findStr = ["dfc", "fc", "ds"]

Approach:

In the 1st Query, the required suffix is "dfc". The strings that have this suffix are [asdfc, tertdfc]. Hence, the count is 2.

In 2nd query, the required suffix is "fc". The strings that have this suffix are [asdfc, asfc, vdsfc, tertdfc]. Hence, the count is 4.

In 3rd query, the required suffix is "ds". The strings that have this suffix are [trgfds, egregds, rtyergds]. Hence, the count is 3.

**Hence the output is [2,4,3].**

But When I'm trying to do this using my code I'm getting **wrong output [2,6,10]**. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here ?

```
class FindCount {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] strr = new String[]{"asdfc", "asfc", "vdsfc", "trgfds", "egregds", "tertdfc", "rtyergds"};

        String[] findStr = new String[]{"dfc", "fc", "ds"};
        int count = 0;
        int result[] = new int[findStr.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < findStr.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < strr.length; j++) {
                count += findCount(strr[j], findStr[i]);
            }
            result[i] = count;
        }
        for(int l: result)
        System.out.println(l);
    }

    static int findCount(String str, String findStr) {
        int lastIndex = 0;
        int count = 0;

        while (lastIndex != -1) {

            lastIndex = str.indexOf(findStr, lastIndex);
            if (lastIndex != -1) {
                count++;
                lastIndex += findStr.length();
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not allowed to use `String.endsWith`?

Comment: `findCount` *can* in your case return numbers bigger than `1` which makes no sense, either the str ends with suffix or it does not, returning 2 does not make sense. In fact you only check if the string contains the suffix, not if it is at the end. That results in 10 being 2 + 4 (from the first two runs which are incorrectly added on top) + 3 (the matches of "ds") + 1 (the extra match in "vdsfc"). A string like "dfcdsdfcdsxxx" would throw your script off quite good.

Answer (score 2):

- You should make the `count` variable local to the first loop so that the count starts at 0 for each suffix.
- Use [`String#endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-) to check if a string ends with a particular suffix, and increment the count by 1 each time this is true.

```java
for (int i = 0; i < findStr.length; i++) {
    int count = 0;
    for(String str: strr)
        if(str.endsWith(findStr[i])) ++count;
    result[i] = count;
}
for(int l: result)
    System.out.println(l);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset `count` to 0 at the beginning of each iteration.
Otherwise it will count the occurrences of the previous substrings as well.

```
for (int i = 0; i < findStr.length; i++) {
    count = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < strr.length; j++) {
        count += findCount(strr[j], findStr[i]);
    }
    result[i] = count;
}
```

Comment: Turamarth Giving wrong output [2 4 4]. Output should be [2 4 3]. Btw thank you. Solution given by @Unmitigated works fine. :)